# How do I trim down a composed Tweet when it exceeds 140 charcters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I have a tweet function that removes @-mentions and will not tweet given the following conditions:
1) if question isn't same as the answer,
2) if composed tweet is greater than 140 characters and
3) if tweet is possibly sensitive.

Works fine but I would rather trim down the composed `answer` if its length exceeds 140. Ideally, I want to chop off all but the first 137 characters and add "..." I am unsure of what best approach would be.

How would trimming down this tweet be achieved?

Here is the current code:

```
function(tweet) {

var question = tweet.txt;
var answer = tweet.txt + "some text";

if(question !== answer && answer.length < 140 && !tweet.possibly_sensitive) {
       answer = answer.replace(/@/g, "."); //removes @-mentions.
       return { id_str: tweet.id_str, text: answer };
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the end of the answer string using [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) which is provided by the String Object in JavaScript.

```
// returns a new answer string containing the first 137 characters
// with '...' tacked onto the end
answer = answer.slice(0,137) + '...'; `
```

Comment: this is what I chose to do `answer = answer.replace(/@/g, ".").slice(0,137) + '...';` Should I update my original question with solution?

Comment: @filmplane I don't believe that will be necessary, you've marked the answer and you've commented. That should suffice.